# SwiftUI programmatically add text or button to a Zstack

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Is there any way to simply append or insert a Text() or other View programmatically? Something like you click a button, or use a tap gesture on a view to insert a new View?

I was imagining it would be like

```
var body: some View {    
  ZStack{ Text("some text") }.gesture( TapGesture().onChanged(self.add( Text("some new text") )))
}
```

Or something like that, but it doesn't seem to be supported and I'm not finding any documented way to insert new items. If that's not possible, what's the alternative to dynamically adding elements like this? Just create an entirely new view with the elements I want?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific what kind of view do you want to add and when ?

Comment: Honestly pretty much what I said dead on. When I tap on the screen I want to add a Text() instance or TextField(). I understand how to create a static View with Text inside it, but I just don't understand how to allow the user to add/remove them dynamically

Comment: Well is it a Text or a TextField? Is it just 1 or many? Wouldn't adding a bunch of different views over each other in a ZStack look weird?

Comment: Let's stick with Text. Yeah it might, I'm just learning is all. The effect is to be able to add Text and then drag them around the screen to wherever you want. Each time you tap, another Text is added.

Comment: Oh you didn't mention they had to be draggable, you might want to take a look at this https://gist.github.com/ohayon/83305d9c48e4fc3e7c3851ba10ddc4c9 , as for adding new elements you can do like I wrote below and just add items to an array.

Comment: Yeah I didn't mention it because I already have that working. I didn't want to make my question overly complicated, but I can see how it didn't communicate what I was envisioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@State private var myviews = ["some text"]
var body: some View {
  VStack {
    ForEach(myviews, id: \.self) { myview in
        Text(myview)
    }
    Button(action: {self.addview()}) {
                Text("Show details")
    }
 }
    private func addView() {
        self.myviews.append("some new text")
    }
}
```

Something like this? Not sure what's the result you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Ya thank you very much. I feel like this was obvious but I'm new to this work/app flow